# NET SDK for Universal Windows App

Tags: .net

I have hardware which come with a SDK for .NET development and requires .NET 2 above.

Is it possible to use that SDK to build Universal Windows App?

Comment: Show more about the hardware. If it indeed points to .NET Framework 2.0 or .NET Compact Framework 2.0, then it won't be UWP friendly, as it can be too old or too limited.

Comment: its a fingerprint sensor by digitalpersona

Comment: Based on what's said on its web site http://devportal.digitalpersona.com/ you can only use it on .NET Framework or Compact Framework and no UWP. You can always call their support or presale to get more information than asking on Stack Overflow.